# (JavaScript) Text appears for short time when using button onclick

Tags: javascript, web

I am making a simple web site program which would show the user text input after the user types some text and clicks the button. For that I made a function called "textWrite()", which would execute when the button OK is clicked. However, when I click the button, the text appears for a really short period of time and quickly after disappears.

Here's my code:

```css
body {
 background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Sava_river_in_Belgrade,_view_from_Kalemegdan_fortress.jpg);
}

#inputCharacter {
 height: 400px;
 width: 400px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 60, 200, 0.6);
 position: relative;
 left: 560px;
 top: 80px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#inputField {
 height: 20px;
 width: 260px;
 margin-left: 65px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 padding: 5px;
}

#heading {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 top: 90px;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: Verdana;
}

#submit {
 height: 30px;
 width: 60px;
 margin-left: 170px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: limegreen;
 border: 3px solid black;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Character Split</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="inputDesign.css">
</head>
<body>
 <form id="inputCharacter">
  <h2 id="heading">Type some text</h2>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="inputField" autocomplete="off"> <br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="textWrite()">OK</button>
  <p id="output">
   <script type="text/javascript">

  function textWrite () {

   var inputValue = document.getElementById('inputField').value;
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = inputValue;
  }

 </script> 
  </p>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: form is submitting ,so page is getting reloaded.prevent the form from getting submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<button>` is in a `<form>`, and the default built-in action in response to a button click in a form is for the form to be submitted. Your page is reloading.

Use `type=button` instead of `type=submit` for the `<button>`.